# Construct std::function from function with one known input argument and one unknown input argument

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I have the function

```
int testFunctionA(double a,std::string b)
{
    return 0;
}
```

of which I want to make a `std::function<int(std::string)>` in which `a` is known and `b` is unknown. So something like

```
std::function<int(std::string)> testFunctionB=testFunctionA(2.3,std::string b);
```

but this syntax does not work.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Go open your C++ book, and go to the chapter that talks about `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
std::function<int(std::string)> testFunc = 
         std::bind(&testFunction, 2.3, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Or a lambda (preferably):

```
std::function<int(std::string)> testFunc = 
        [](std::string str){ return testFunction( 2.3, str ); };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lambda:

```
auto func = [](std::string b){ return testFunction( 2.3, b ); };
```

Note: `func` will have some compiler generated type, but it will be implicitly convertible to a `std::function< int( std::string ) >`.